# How do I remove these corner markers /edge markers?

Tags: overleaf, edge, cropmarks

Hello everyone out there. I'm currently writing my thesis in Overleaf and for some reason all of my pages have these edge markers on them. How do I remove them?

[image: corner markers]

```
 \documentclass[oneside,12pt]{maththesis}
\usepackage{graphicx,verbatim,amsthm}
%\usepackage{tikz,cancel,stmaryrd,multicol}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}

\setlength\parindent{0.5in}
\lstset{language=Matlab,%
    %basicstyle=\color{red},
    breaklines=true,%
    morekeywords={matlab2tikz},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
    morekeywords=[2]{1}, keywordstyle=[2]{\color{black}},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},%
    stringstyle=\color{mylilas},
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},%
    showstringspaces=false,%without this there will be a symbol in the places where there is a space
    numbers=left,%
    numberstyle={\tiny \color{black}},% size of the numbers
    numbersep=9pt, % this defines how far the numbers are from the text
    emph=[1]{for,end,break},emphstyle=[1]\color{red}, %some words to emphasise
    %emph=[2]{word1,word2}, emphstyle=[2]{style},    
}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{illustration}[theorem]{Illustration}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\begin{document}


\ThesisAuthor{Name Name }
\ThesisTitle{ON FIBONACCI POWER SERIES}
%% Add \boldmath inside the thesis title if there are math symbols in the title
\GraduationMoYr{August 2022}

%\ThesisStyle{MS}{Final}{-10pt}{15pt}
%% Choices for the 1st argument: MS, PhD
%% Choices for the 2nd argument: Final, FinalWithCorner, Draft
%%%% Use Draft to skip some pages that are not needed for now

    \FrontMatter

\input{acknowledgements}
%Use \input to add the file saved in the same directory
%with name, for this example: acknowledgements.tex
\input{abstract}


\tableofcontents
%to generate the table of contents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
%to generate a list of figures page

\MainMatter

\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}
\input{chapter3}
\input{chapter4}
\input{chapter5}


\input{bibliography}

%\BackMatter
%% Use \BackMatter only if there is an Appendix
%\input{appendixA}
%\input{appendixB}
%\input{appendixC}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The class you used isn't a standard one. Properly some setting in your `maththesis.cls` file.

Comment: Got it. thank you. I'll try and post the mathtesis.csl file inside my question